# XPath to select link containing text?

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I tried to use this XPath:

```
//*[contains(normalize-space(text()),'Jira')]
```

Also tried:

```
//*[contains(text(),'Jira')]
```

In the below HTML example, there is space before and after text "Jira". I am not able to click on the link:

```
<a href="#/crm/usergroup-edit?id=572a3c84e4b07f6189958700" 
   ng-repeat="gp in groups | filter : userGroupSearch | orderBy:'-name':1" 
   class="ng-scope">
    <div class="inventoryPanel" ng-style="myStyle" style="width: 15.8%;">
        <h4 class="ng-binding">
            <div class="groupIcon G">
                <div class="text ng-binding">P</div>
            </div>Jira
         </h4>
    </div>
 </a>
```

Comment: <div class="inventoryPanel" ng-style="myStyle" style="width: 15.8%;">
                <h4 class="ng-binding">
                    <div class="groupIcon W">
                         <div class="text ng-binding">J</div>
                    </div>New Jira
                </h4>
            </div>
        </a>

Comment: Be careful selecting wildcard tags that partially match text. Such locators may be too broad and match anything :)

Comment: @JockX: Your comment points out a risk of any selection criteria when OP includes only a fragment; we can be more selective if given more context.

Answer (score 2):

The following XPath will select all `a` elements whose string value contains a `Jira` substring:

```
//a[contains(.,'Jira')]
```

Comment: the above is bring more then one element but i need only with text jira ...it need to be click ..please suggest

Comment: Then you must refine your stated selection criteria; this provides what you asked for.

Comment: i facing similar issue  I tried xpath //h3[text()='Available Customers']/parent::div/following-sibling::div//li//div[@class='longText ng-binding ng-scope']//i[@ng-show='item.selected'] but didn't worked
    
    There is space before shetty ruat pravin ruat(pravin.uat@gmail.com) so cannot reach till there and or gettext